# Copying column values in SharePoint document library

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Trying to copy non-empty values from column x000 to x001.
The list contains over 11k files, and script goes through all of them, while values for field x000 is filled only for 900 files. is it possible to modify script, so that PnPListItem gets only files which have non-empty values of x000 column?

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://contoso.com/site"
$ListName = "mylist" 
$SourceColumn = "x000" #Internal Name of the Fields
$DestinationColumn = "x001"
 
#Connect to PnP Online

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
  
#Get all items from List
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $Listname -PageSize 500

Write-host "Total Number of List Items:" $($ListItems.Count)
 
#Copy Values from one column to another

ForEach ($Item in $ListItems)
{
    Set-PnPListItem -List $Listname -Identity $Item.Id -Values @{$DestinationColumn = $Item[$SourceColumn]}
}
```

Comment: have you tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/isnotnull-element-query combined with https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPListItem.html#example-5 ? basically get all the items you are looking for with an appropriate CAML query

Comment: I also found the same thing as Jimas, it looks like CAML query is your best bet. It looks like all other queries are for all items. I think best you're gonna get otherwise is filtering after you get your items like: `$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $Listname -PageSize 500 | Where-Object {$_}`.

Answer (score 0):

Get-PnPListItem with -Query (CAML query) and -PageSize will not work with lists larger than 5000 items. Even if you only use CAML query with RowLimit tag you will end up hitting the classic ListViewThreshold limit error.

Since your list has 11k items you'll need to use:

```
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $Listname -PageSize 5000 | where-object {$_["x000"] -ne ""}
```